# info.php shows log_errors is Off but it is set to be On in the php.ini of Loaded Configuration File

Tags: debugging, php

PHP info page shows that `log_errors` is set `Off` even tho I set it On

*in info.php page shows:*

- `Loaded Configuration File` -> `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`
- `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` -> `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d`

*top portion of altered php.ini file:*

```
[PHP]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

I have tracked the rest of php.ini file and found other log_error reference which I have also set On
    log_errors = On

I am not sure if I should use ini_set('display_errors', 1); format in .ini files, I have found answers about this and used everything to test if anything worked but still.

So what's wrong with config?

Note: yes, I have restarted apache2.

Using up to date Ubuntu Server x64 16.04 running PHP Version 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

won't work in ini file.
to enable error reporting write following line in your ini file

> error_reporting = E_ALL

for more info refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)